# Recreate James Blake "Retrograde" synth chorus opening

Tags: synthesizer, cubase

In Cubase, I want to recreate James Blake "Retrograde" synth chorus opening (starting at [1:36](https://youtu.be/XClvMMxBg1k?si=0Z-EFN8YXCGT0uMz&t=96)). To be precise - since there are several synths layered there - I specifically want [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nC9JQ1BjHeg) (this is a recreation link, but not in Cubase. [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoD2URJ6NJk) is the same).

Since I'm really new to this, I'd be satisfied with a pretty basic recreation rather than an advanced one.

As a simplification, I thought about just making a volume automation that just increases the volume from low db to high db. However, it doesn't get the right effect.

What's a basic way to achieve this?

Comment: Cubase is a DAW, not a synthesiser.  Do you have a synthesiser plugin?  If so, isn't everything covered in detail in the tutorial videos you link?